# registration does not work

Tags: python, django

Hi i created RegistrationForm, view etc - i think everything what i need to give user possibility to register. But when i am on register site, i fill form and click "register" the site is refreshed and nothing happened, i get this same blank form. What can be issue? My django version is 1.9.1.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class MyregistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyregistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyregistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

view:

```
from .forms import *
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response


    def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyregistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('congratulations')

        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))

        args['form'] = MyregistrationForm()
        return render_to_response('page/register.html', args)

    def congratulations(request):
        return render_to_response('page/congratulations.html')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
url(r'^congratulations/$', views.congratulations, name='congratulations')
```

register template:

```
<form action="/register/" method="post">{%csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        </form>
```

Comment: It is possible that the form is not valid. Do you see anything when you do `print form.errors` after the `if form.is_valid()` block ?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently creating a new form for POST requests when the form is invalid. That means you don't see the form errors.

Instead, you can move the `MyregistrationForm()` into the `else` statement, so that it only runs for GET requests. To do this you need to rearrange the view slightly. I've switched from `render_to_response` to `render` to make this easier.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyregistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('congratulations')
    else:
        form = MyregistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'page/register.html', {'form': form})
```

With your new view, you should see the form errors in the template. This will give you a clue why the form is invalid.